# Following the Get Started: Stack server stuck loading page endlessly

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've been following the [docker get started guide](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part3/#scale-the-app) quite closely - except for a few changes in my python app, which I have confirmed are working without issue from the version I have pushed to docker hub.

However, when I get to Part 3 and attempt to load up `localhost:80`, the page simply loads endlessly.

My commands:

```
$ docker swarm init
Swarm initiated: ...
$ docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml
Creating network getstartedlab_webnet
Creating service getstartedlab_web
$ docker stack ps getstartedlab
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE                     NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
fhxqr2u8hxar        getstartedlab_web.1   mctague/friendlyhello:2   cube                Running             Running 29 seconds ago                       
4t9mu9r8147e        getstartedlab_web.2   mctague/friendlyhello:2   cube                Running             Running 28 seconds ago                       
duute2pvgu9z        getstartedlab_web.3   mctague/friendlyhello:2   cube                Running             Running 30 seconds ago                       
9kav6v27qfjn        getstartedlab_web.4   mctague/friendlyhello:2   cube                Running             Running 29 seconds ago                       
1s2imbiuk6e2        getstartedlab_web.5   mctague/friendlyhello:2   cube                Running             Running 29 seconds ago                       
$ docker logs <one of the running containers>
 * Running on http://0.0.0.0:80/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
$ curl localhost:80
< either an endless loading that I have to cancel with ^C,
  *OR* Connection refused >
```

---

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  web:
    image: mctague/friendlyhello:2
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: have you tried to simplyfy your example? try to deploy only 1 replica, give it a bit more resources and start it without the restart policy (one possible error source).

Comment: @Gabbax0r still behaves exactly the same, with either infinite loading or no loading at all

Comment: What application are you running? Can't be sure by the image name you have `mctague/friendlyhello`. Can you also share the contents of your Dockerfile?

Comment: @JulioHM my dockerfile looks like so: https://pastebin.com/eJC9qnf3, as seen in the Getting Started tutorial. The app itself works fine when I run it outside of docker-compose.

Comment: I was able to run your exact `docker-compose.yml` on my machine. All five replicas came up normally and `curl localhost:80` works fine for me here. When you say "endless loading" does that mean your app is not responding and curl hangs until terminated?

Comment: @JulioHM Yep, that's what it's doing. There's nothing else listening on port 80, so it isn't a conflict over access to the port, either. Perhaps I should try on my remote machine over SSH, or reinstall docker?

Comment: Hard to tell from here. I would try to run from any other image, and determine if you really can't reach the service. For example, try running the official apache image, which is also simple enough. A few other steps I can think of is try changing the port binding on the host side, try higher ports other than 80. Disable any firewall rules momentarily for testing. As a side test, you can `docker exec ContainerID /bin/sh` to access the shell inside running containers, and check if they can see each other propertly; `curl` into one another from inside the overlay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143337/discussion-between-juliohm-and-ethan-mctague).

Comment: I am seeing this exact issue with Arch Linux and Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658bed64 (see https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-network-issue-getting-started-services-curl-http-localhost-hangs/32357). The link to the chat is broken, was this resolved?

Comment: @Gyppo I have the same issue with the same software

Answer (score 8):

In some systems, curl connects to ip6 by default for localhost. So you can run curl  using:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:80
```

or

```
$ curl -4 localhost:80
```

Answer (score 5):

Alexey's answer was my issue too. I resolved the issue disabling ipv6 (and therefore defaulting to ipv4) by adding the following 2 lines (this is on CentOS 7) to **/etc/sysctl.conf**:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

then executing `sysctl -p` (all as root/su).